# Use of the word 'desire'

Tags: terminology

I want to know about the word desire used in religious texts. Does the word 'desire' alone represents 'sexual desire'? Supposing, if we say:

> Those who refrain from desire, God is pleased with them.

In this the word desire is meant the sexual desire. Does this suffice? Is this understandable that the writer means sexual desire by writing only the word 'desire'?

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing which texts and which religions you are referring to! And it would then become more of a theological than a grammatical issue!

Comment: I am simply asking if native understand 'desire' to be as sexual desire? Take an example of the entry [She felt a surge of love and desire for him.] on: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/desire_1?q=desire

Comment: *Burning love and desire* is an expression often used of the feelings of Christian mystics, such as Teresa of Avila, towards God. Whether such feelings were in any way *erotic* is hard to say. But it is certainly implied in your example.

Comment: Without additional context, I would say no, it's not understandable that the word _desire_ in your sentence represents only sexual desire.

Comment: [What Does the Bible Say About Desire?](https://www.openbible.info/topics/desire) So far as I can see, not one of the dozens of biblical quotes in that link featuring the word ***desire*** have any allusions to *sexual* desire. And any dictionary should make it clear that particular "sub-sense" isn't *inherently* part of the word's meaning in all contexts. Deciding whether it applies in OP's cited context is a matter of Off Topic personal opinions and social / cultural / religious perspectives, not just the actual words themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Desire does not only mean sexual desire. Indeed in Buddhism we have the "noble truth" that "All suffering is caused by desire". We know from the rest of Buddhist tradition that this isn't "sexual desire", it covers all forms of desire.

If you mean "sexual desire" you need to use the adjective, or provide sufficient context for the readers to understand.

> She felt a surge of love and desire for him  (Sexual desire, from the context)
>
> You should refrain from desire. (could be desire for anything)
>
> You should refrain from sexual desire (explict)
>
> Men should refrain from the desire of women (implictly sexual)
>
> Men should refrain from the desire of doughnuts. (not sexual)

Answer (score 1):

I believe in this context only you can take that "desire" refers to *any* "bad desires" (whatever that religion defines as bad), such as *greed*. But you can't take it that the word "desire" alone always means that in any context, religious or otherwise.

Most religious texts were written in ancient languages and subsequently translated into modern languages like English. It surprises some to learn that far from being simplistic or primitive, many ancient languages were far more complex than the languages of today.

Take the Bible for example - the Christian part of the bible was translated mainly from ancient Greek texts. They had multiple words to describe different aspects of "love" - such as love for your family, which is very different from romantic love. But in English we just have the one word - we can love our wife, and we can love chips, not really the same thing at all! But **context** should determine how you understand it.

Likewise with the word "desire", you should consider the context.

I'm not assuming you are speaking exclusively about Judeo-Christian religion here - but to show that the word can be used both positively and negatively in a religious context I can give you two example texts from the Christian bible where they are quite different. The ancient Greek word translated "desire" is *e·pi·thy·meʹo*. This word is used at 1 John 2:17 in a negative way, to describe people with "bad" desires - it also speaks of different *kinds* of desires which proves it is not just referring to sexual desire. However Hebrews 6:11 uses a form of the same word in a positive way, to indicate that the writer "desired" good things for those he was writing to.

The context of these two passages makes the connotations of the word clear.

By way of a disclaimer I should just point out that I have endeavored to give this answer in the most secular way possible. I have used inverted commas around any point of religious belief to show that I am quoting in context rather than making a statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no.

More context is needed to understand if 'desire' in your sentence means 'sexual desire' or not. It can also be 'desire for materialistic pleasures' or 'desire for sensual pleasures - food, sex or something else'.

Desire means having a strong want for something, and that want is usually so strong, specially when used in religious contexts, that it starts interrupting your mental piece and becomes a cause of unhappiness in your life.

Since the writer has used only 'desire' in this sentence, my assumption is that he/she must've detailed on the types of desire he is referring to in the preceding sentences which might give you some context to understand what he means by it.